# ASP.NET Roles with Windows Auth

Tags: asp.net, roles, windows-authentication, admin

Super simple question from an ASP newb: I've got an internal-only ASP.NET website I'm working on that uses Windows integrated auth across the board. There are essentially three roles I want to associate with the site: user, manager, and admin. The site is open to the entire org, so anyone who is authenticated is a user, unless they are a manager or an admin.

The list of admins and managers needs to be in a database, not in the web.config. The role information for this site is not in any way associated with what can be learned from a user's AD profile.

I've been picking up ASP.NET pretty quickly and I'm definitely capable of researching the correct solution, but I was hoping someone could start me down the right road here. What's the best way to get this done? I imagine it involves using a role provider on top of the integrated auth, but before I started researching a million options and possibly picked the wrong one, I thought I'd ask here.

Thanks!

Comment: Having your network admins stick the managers and admins into AD groups (such as MyCustomAppAdmin) works nicely. Would you reconsider this?

Comment: It's a possibility, and one that will be carefully considered. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to do this also and I used the below blog entry from Scott Guthrie to get me going....

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/Recipe_3A00_-Implementing-Role_2D00_Based-Security-with-ASP.NET-2.0-using-Windows-Authentication-and-SQL-Server.aspx

Worked great for me.

I didn't create a new provider or anything.  Scott's blog post lays it out nicely.  Although it is quite a hack but got me going quickly and did the trick.

With this trick you can use windows auth with DB based roles.

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use MembershipProvider using ActiveDirectory [Info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998345.aspx)