# How to create Roles and Manage Users in terms of Roles

Tags: asp.net-membership, roles

I am sure the question that i am going to ask must have been answered a billion times before...but I have been reading so many articles about membership and role management that my head is spinning right now and i think i am a little confused too.....

I am really looking to implement role management for Admin interface of my site. I have a general idea about membership and role management but really dont know where and how to start implementation of the same on my site....

If some one could direct me to any tutorials or examples or any walk through that implements role management then it will really be of great help.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

This question has been askied before.

see [ASP.NET Roles with Windows Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423196/asp-net-roles-with-windows-auth)

If you implement your own role provider for example and you store the data in say a database, then you would need a UI to manage those tables. Most likely you'll have a users table and a roles table and a table in bettwen to do the mapping.